# Referencing Array from other View Controller Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am attempting to work a segmented control to display data from a search into categories. However although data is received it is not being displayed on my table. Here is my code for the two View Controllers. The child View controller is the one in which the UITableView is stored.

**PARENT VC**

```
- (void)searchPeople:(NSString*)text {
    if(![text isEqualToString:@""]){
        PFQuery *userWithName = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
        [userWithName whereKey:@"fullName" containsString:text];

        PFQuery *userWithHandle = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
        [userWithHandle whereKey:@"username" containsString:text];

        PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[userWithHandle,userWithName]];
        [userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"USERS: %@",results);
            [self.userResults removeAllObjects];
            [self.userResults addObjectsFromArray:results];
            [[ArrayManager sharedInstance].searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];
            NSLog(@"Count Number: %@", [ArrayManager sharedInstance].searchResults);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reload_data" object:self];
        }];
    }
}
```

**CHILD VC**

```
-(void)handle_data {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Object Entries: %lu", (unsigned long)[[ArrayManager sharedInstance].searchResults count]);
    NSMutableArray * array = [[ArrayManager sharedInstance] getGlobalArray];

    return [array count];
}

- (void)tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *data = [[ArrayManager sharedInstance]init].searchResults[indexPath.row];
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = data[@"objectId"];
    return cell;
}
```

Data is returned fine from the server however, there is no data being displayed on the table. The `ArrayManager` class is a Singleton class.

Comment: where are you listening observer in  child vc? Child VC should register reload_data observer in ViewDidload and you should update table array in that method

Comment: How is the table notified to reload?

Comment: One more thing parse does not support containsString matching , it just allows beginsWith ,endsWith or full value matching

Comment: You certainly need to add an observer in the child VC which listens to a post notification... Nonetheless, wouldn't it be easier to work with a delegate rather than notifications and singleton?

Comment: there is an observer @MuhammadAdnan I just didnt include it in the post. the issue lies with the array

Comment: Why would you init the singleton again in cell for row ?
"[[ArrayManager sharedInstance]init].searchResults[indexPath.row];"

Answer (score 0):

Create a Data Access Object (DAO) and store all information in an array in that.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm

Have both VC's change and access the DAO instead of each other. It is much simpler that way.